# Open website on left click in trade platforms

Tags: pine-script, href, indicator, sierrachart

I have a website that takes a price level and a symbol as arguments and makes some visualisations on it. I'm a programmer for some traders who uses either NinjaTrader, TradingView, or Sierra Chart, and I want to add a functionality to any of these platforms where I can click on a price level (possibly with a hotkey) and it will open my webpage with the symbol and price level passed as arguments.

I was wondering if it's possible to add this functionality to any of these platforms, and if so, could you guide me on how to do it? For example, if I'm using NinjaTrader, how can I write an indicator that listens for a left-click event on the chart and opens a URL with the symbol and price level as arguments?

Let's say I have an url `www.example.com/personalVisualise?target=<price>&asset=<symbol>`

In tradingview I have this indicator as start point, but do not know how to continue. How can I open a webpage or open another tool from this indicator.

```
//@version=5
    indicator("Point", overlay=true)
    myPrice = input.price(100, inline="Point", confirm=true)
    myTime = input.time(timestamp("2020-02-20"), inline="Point", confirm=true)
```

Comment: Not possible for pinescript.